# How to convert user inputted char to its numerical position in Java?

Tags: java

So I'm stuck on this problem in my Java intro class. I'm a complete newbie at this stuff, so any help is appreciated. I have to design and create a program that accepts a user inputted letter (which should be either a-z or A-Z) and determine what position it holds in the alphabet. (so a would equal 0) I keep having issues with string to char and char to int conversions. Any tips or leads on how to design this program would be much appreciated. I've been working on this program literally all day and haven't had made any discernible progress.

Comment: Okay cool, but how would I go about getting the user-inputted char? Sorry again man, but I'm really new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the `char` constant `'a'` from your input char.
Try the following code:

```
char c = 'b';
System.out.println(c - 'a' + 1);
```

The output will be `2`.

Comment: The output should be 2 for the letter b.

Comment: a --> 0, b --> 2? @codeNinja

Comment: a is the first letter in the alphabet and therefore a --> 1, b --> 2. @Weibo Li

Comment: But in your question, you said `determine what position it holds in the alphabet. (so a would equal 0)`

Comment: My apologies, I did not see that. By the way it's not my question. @Weibo Li

Comment: I've modified my code to match your requirement. @codeNinja

Comment: Okay, this looks good but how can I set it up so that the user can choose which letter to input?

Comment: So here's my code so far and I just can't figure out how to get this thing to work:

package Lab02;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab02_1 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Scanner sc = new Scanner("abc");
  System.out.print("Enter your letter");
  char ch = sc.findInLine(".");
     System.out.println(sc.next()); // prints "bc
  
     
  
  System.out.println(ch - 'a' + 1);
 }

}

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a user inputted *anything* use a Scanner. In this case the following code will prompt the user for a character then assign that to a variable called 'c'.

```
import java.util.*;

// assuming that the rest of this code is inside of the main method or wherever
// you want to put it.
System.out.print("Enter the letter: ");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

char c = Character.valueOf(input.next());
```

Then using this code use whatever method you like to convert to alphabetical position. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think it was answered already but putting it all together:

```
    /**
    * Gets the numerical position of the given character.
    */
    private static final int convertToPosition(final char c) {
        return c - 'A' + 1; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("Enter the letter: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (input.hasNext()) { // if there is an input
            String inStr = input.next().toUpperCase();
            if (inStr.length() != 1) {
                System.out.println("Unknown letter");
                return;
            }
            char c = inStr.charAt(0);
            int pos = convertToPosition(c);
            System.out.println("Position: " + pos);
        } else {
            System.out.println("no input");
        }
    }
```